# Split vim window with one file read/write and one file read-only

Tags: vim

I am editing a file using vim.  I want to open another file (which currently exists) from within the same vim session and split my screen doing so.  I want it to be read-only because I don't want to risk accidentally editing it.

If I try `:sp another_file.txt`, it opens it in read/write mode.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:view` command is what you are looking for. It opens buffer in readonly mode.

You can try `:sv file.txt` to open file in split window.