# How to open some files/directories read-write, others read-only

Tags: vim

This is similar to "[Split vim window with one file read/write and one file read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795986/split-vim-window-with-one-file-read-write-and-one-file-read-only)".

From the command line, I want to open files in one directory as read-write, and files in another directory as read-only. How do I do this?

For example:

```
vim read-write-dir/**/* read-only-dir/**/* # zsh
```

Listing the files individually isn't an option, there's a large number of files under each directory (I use bufExplorer).

My motivation is, I'm editing two programs in different OSX Terminal tabs, and Vim gets unhappy about a file being edited twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a read-only file and read-write file while starting Vim, you can use the `-c` option in your terminal:

```
vim -c ":view file_read_only" file_read_write
```

Then you can switch between them using `:e #`